# qemu-img convert CentOS7 vmdk to qcow2 and vice versa error

Tags: centos7, qemu, vmware-vmdk, convert, qcow2

I'm trying to **convert CentOS7 from VMDK to QCOW2 and vice versa** using qemu-img convert command. 
when uploading the new Templates (OVF with the new converted vmdk and KVM template with the new converted qcow2 to KVM server) I'm getting errors.

1. [dracut error from KVM Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mi6.png)
   the uuid stands for '/' filesystem, when I do rescue mode the VM looks okay
    then running the commands without errors and with no success:

   `mount -n -o remount,rw /dev/vda1`
   `mount -a`

   I've tried many other solutions but this solution is common.
2. OVF - the screen stuck in upload mode (you can see only '_' on the screen)
   when choosing rescue mode the vm looks okay as well and here is [dmesg output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38NVs.png).
    it doesn't seem there is an error, maybe dpdk error but I'm not sure if it should stuck the vm (I'm newbie in dpdk and didn't find any good information about this error). 

   I'm running qemu-img convert command on CentOS 7.3.1611 and qemu-img version is 1.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just posting the answer of my question because I didn't find it while searching online.
to convert CentOS7 vmdk to qcow2 I used [virt-v2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v.1.html) command and it works like magic.
cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, however, you could try

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

I was converting VMDK to VHDX using this soft, and job was done.

Comment: starWind is windows based solution and my env is centOS7. thanks anyhow